# mysql vlookup duplicated values

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I want to create mysql query which will show the following result from this table:

Table:

```
id - projectteam - person - transfered
1 - barcelona - messi - 1
2 - realm - ronaldo - 0
3 - manutd - messi - 0
```

Result:

```
player - from - to
messi - barcelona - manutd
ronaldo - null - realm
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Suppose Messi now transfers from Man U to AC Milan: how does your schema reflect that the transfer was from Man U and not from Barcelona?  Moreover, how would you expect your results to look in such a situation?

Comment: I allow only one transfer per season in my game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the basis that you have a maximum of one transfer per player, you can simply make an outer self-join:

```
SELECT      t.person, f.projectteam `from`, t.projectteam `to`
FROM        my_table t
  LEFT JOIN my_table f
         ON f.person = t.person
        AND f.transfered = 1
WHERE       t.transfered = 0
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d71c1a/1/0).